# How to stock array with localStorage (Chrome Extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to stock an array in localStorage but then I read it was impossible. So I tried that:

```
    array = {};
    array.name =        $('[name="name"]').val();
    array.username =    $('[name="username"]').val();
    array.password =    $('[name="password"]').val();
    
    alert(localStorage['accounts']);
    local = JSON.parse(localStorage['accounts']);
    localu = local.push(array);
    alert(JSON.stringify(localu));
```

In fact the scripts stops at the first alert which returns '[]' (I previously put that value to check the result).

Why isn't my script working?

Comment: Why is `array` not an array? (not that its the problem)

Comment: `array` is an array Oo `array = {};` It does the same think that `array = new Array`, no ?

Comment: No. `{}` is an object literal, same as `new Object`. `[]` is the array literal, identical to `new Array`. Javascript Arrays cannot contain key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript, `{}` is an Object. `[]` is an Array.

`var array = []` and `var array = new Array()` do the same thing.

An array is an ordered container of stuff, each value has an index not a key.

An object is a named container of stuff, each "stuff" has a key.

Your `array` is definitely an object.

```
var data = {};
data.name =        $('[name="name"]').val();
data.username =    $('[name="username"]').val();
data.password =    $('[name="password"]').val();

alert(localStorage['accounts']);
// > undefined OR the value
local = JSON.parse(localStorage['accounts']);
// local contains a parsed version of localStorage['accounts']
localu = local.push(array);
// localu = 0 (push returns the length i think?)
alert(JSON.stringify(localu));
```

Try the following. I've not tested it, but might work.

```
var data = {};
data.name =        $('[name="name"]').val();
data.username =    $('[name="username"]').val();
data.password =    $('[name="password"]').val();

if (localStorage['accounts'] == undefined) { // fixed
// does the key exist? No so create something to get us started
   localu = { accounts: [] };
} else {
// the key exists! lets parse it
   localu = JSON.parse(localStorage['accounts']);
}
// add the new "data" to the list
localu.accounts.push(data);
// save the results (we have to stringify it)
localStorage['accounts'] = JSON.stringify(localu);
```

Comment: Thank you but your script failed here ! `'undefined'` because it is juste `undefined` :) And thank you for the precision of what is an array and an object. I didn't know that.